# How can I view the list of packages that were "suggested" by apt?

Tags: debian, apt

When installing a package using `apt-get install package` a list of "Suggested packages" is displayed. What command can be used to print it again?

Comment: If you're just interested in the information, you could have a look at the `sug` entries at, say [`http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gnome`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gnome).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here are a couple additional options:

1. `apt-cache depends <package_name>` will give you dependency info about a package (installed or not) including *Suggests*.
2. `apt-rdepends -s Suggests <package_name>` will list the *Suggests* for a package and its dependencies. The `apt-rdepends` command is provided by its own package, *apt*-ly named `apt-rdepends` (forgive the pun).

Answer (score 1):

```
apt show <package_name>
```

For example:

```
$ apt show ffmpeg
Package: ffmpeg
Version: 7:5.1.3-1
...
Suggests: ffmpeg-doc
...
```